# Is it possible to highlight part text of input button value?

Tags: javascript, html, button, input

I'm trying to bold part of the text inside an input button value.
HTML doesn't work inside the value attribute, so tags like `<b>` and `<strong>` and also methods like `bold()` won't work.

Is it possible to bold just part of the text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using an input of type button and adding HTML to the value won't work, but you can just use a button element instead

```
<button><strong>Hello</strong> Kitty</button>
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/ovqpb9rf/)